# Wordpress URL Rewrite not working

Tags: php, plugins, plugin-development

I'm trying to create a custom url rewrite for my wordpress plugin.

```
function insert_plugin_rewrite_rule($rules) {
    global $wp, $wp_rewrite;
    $wp->add_query_var('update_slug');
    $ret = $wp_rewrite->add_rule('updates/plugins/([^/]+)/', 'index.php?update_slug=$matches[1]', 'top');

    // Remove when debugging is done.
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules(false);
}

add_filter('init', 'insert_plugin_rewrite_rule');
```

And to try and intercept it:

```
function blah() {
    global $wp;
    echo "<pre>";print_r($GLOBALS['wp']->query_vars['update_slug']);echo "</pre>";
}
add_filter('init', 'blah');
```

When I'm in the 'blah' function, it shows that my update_slug query var has been registered, and that my url has been registered too. But when I go to /updates/plugins/123/ it doesn't show any query_vars have been set.

Am I doing this right, or is there some subtle thing I'm missing?

Comment: It may also we worth noting that I'm doing my init of 'blah' a few lines after my init of 'insert_plugin_rewrite_rule' in my plugin's main file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first, you should use the proper filter and method to add query vars and rewrite rules and not manipulate the globals directly. the other issue I believe is your regex pattern, this is working for me:

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpa59404_query_vars' );
function wpa59404_query_vars($query_vars){
    $query_vars[] = 'update_slug';
    return $query_vars;
}

add_action( 'init', 'wpa59404_rewrites' );
function wpa59404_rewrites(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'updates/plugins/([^/]+)/?$',
        'index.php?update_slug=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
```

Comment: hey Milo will this work in a functions file of a theme also?